# python for loop iteration in excel

Tags: excel, python-2.7, for-loop, tuples

I have an excel sheet with two different columns from where I want to take data one at a time say data value from A2 and B2 then perform certain operation and then again take values from B3 and C3 and so on.. till B50 and C50. I have written the following code for this but I believe it's not correct. Also I am new to python so don't have much knowledge. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Inputexcel.xlsm')
    sheet = wb['Sheet1'] 
    tup1 = (sheet['A2':'A50'])
    tup2 = (sheet['B2':'B50'])
    for i in range(0,48):      
    text = tup1[i].value
    i+=1
```

I was able to implement it for a single value and also perform the operation by using the below code. But my main aim is to iterate for all the values of excel where I am facing issue. 
Code for single value :

```
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Inputexcel.xlsm')
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    text = sheet['A2'].value
    eid = sheet['B2'].value
```

Also sharing the Operation to be performed if it is of any help :

```
    doc = docx.Document('mydoc.docx')
    doc.paragraphs[9].runs[6].clear()
    doc.paragraphs[9].runs[6].text
    doc.paragraphs[9].add_run(text).bold = True
    doc.save('mydoc ' + str(eid) + '.docx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the Cells in tup1 and tup2 - I would recommend adding the values directly to tup1 and tup2 ...like below:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1'] 
tup1 = []
tup2 = []
for i in range(2,50):
    rowA ='A{0}'.format(i)
    rowB = 'B{0}'.format(i)
    tup1.append(sheet[rowA].value)
    tup2.append(sheet[rowB].value)
print (tup1)
print (tup2)
```

Comment: The irony of calling a list tup :)